# Client Side Web Service

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

**Background:**

I have an HTML file that takes multiple parameters and uses javascript to dynamically render the page. This page is pulling data from multiple static local XML files and processing.

For example, service.html?ID?123 returns a page specific to ID number 123.

That is easy and is done.

**Problem:**

I want to use jQuery ajax to pull the rendered result back to the main page. Currently, I am using something like this:

> $.ajax({
>
> ```
>       type: "GET",
>       url: "service.html?ID?123",
>       success: function(msg){
>           alert( msg );
>       }
> ```
>
> });

However, this correctly returns my html page before my javascript is run. Can anyone think of any workarounds for something like this? I don't want to run the resulting data in the parent.

**Possible Solution:**

*I am thinking of running the "service" in a hidden iframe and have it write to a reusable static html file that I can pull in through ajax. Is something like this viable?*
**nope**: Now that I think of it - I don't think this is a viable solution because all of the processing in the iframe would take control of the javascript thread in the main page. This is exactly what I am trying to avoid

**Edit:**
Also, webworkers won't work because of the environment that I am in (.hta).

Comment: @fluorescentLAMP Shouldn't it be `service.html?ID=123` ?

Comment: If I was feeding it to a .php file, then yes. As I have it now I am parsing the url string on my own so it doesn't really matter. I expected this question to come up.

Comment: What do you mean by "before my javascript is run" ? Is it run at page load? If not,what runs it?

Comment: Sorry, that part wasn't that clear. It returns my .html file as if I opened it in an editor. E.g. nothing has been "run".

Comment: @fluorescentLAMP Why do you want to avoid that the IFRAME "takes control" of the main thread? What's the problem with that?

Comment: Because that makes the entire effort moot. It is no longer asynchronous - which is essentially the point of using ajax. Again - webworkers would be a solution to this but I don't have access to them.

Comment: @flourescentLAMP Ajax is not related to this. Ajax is for making asynchronous HTTP requests. You want to run JavaScript asynchronously and that can only be done with web workers. Ajax cannot help you here.

Comment: @flourescentLAMP Also, you have to write "@Šime" in your comment if you want me to be notified of it. Otherwise, I wont be aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

The IFRAME solution should work. Just place a hidden IFRAME on the page and then load the page into it:

```
$("#the_iframe").attr("src", "service.html?ID?123");
```

That will run the JavaScript code associated with the page. Then, you can access that page (its generated content):

```
var data = $("#the_iframe").contents().find("#data_container");
```

Comment: Now that I think of it - I don't think this is a viable solution because all of the processing in the iframe would take control of the javascript thread in the main page. This is exactly what I am trying to avoid. If I am going to be processing on the same thread I might as well do all of the processing on the same page. This was a good try thou.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood what you need..

```
$(function() {

    $.ajax({

          type: "GET",
          url: "service.html?ID?123",
          success: function(msg){
              alert( msg );
          }   

    });
 }
);
```

Will run that when all the page is loaded, but not rendered. However any element reference made from the Ajax success function will be ok.

Comment: What do you mean by: _"However any element reference made from the Ajax success function will be ok."_?